Apktool decompiles fine but can't recompile
I am currently trying to reverse an APK to be able to delete a permission in the AndroidManifest file. The problem I am facing is that, unchanged or not, the APK can't recompile. Here is the command & results:
pixel@pixels-mint:~/apk$ apktool b ./
I: Using Apktool 2.9.3
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
W: /home/pixel/apk/./res/values/styles.xml:2669: error: expected enum but got (raw string) 2.
W: /home/pixel/apk/./res/values/styles.xml:4305: error: expected dimension but got (raw string) -1.
W: error: failed linking references.
brut.androlib.exceptions.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [/tmp/brut_util_Jar_58207052579450786324862031923249711165.tmp, link, -o, /tmp/APKTOOL15294645067196743982.tmp, --package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 21, --target-sdk-version, 34, --version-code, 154522, --version-name, 13.5.0.41, --no-auto-version, --no-version-vectors, --no-version-transitions, --no-resource-deduping, --allow-reserved-package-id, --no-compile-sdk-metadata, --warn-manifest-validation, -e, /tmp/APKTOOL11298414694208479989.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /home/pixel/.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk, --manifest, /home/pixel/apk/./AndroidManifest.xml, /home/pixel/apk/./build/resources.zip]


I have been trying to find another tool to do the job for 1 day now, and each and every tool I try doesn't seem to be functional from my side.
If you know what's happening here, or can suggest a tool to modify manifests, it would be very appreciated!
(I am using Linux Mint)

Can you provide the sample apk so that we can also test it from our side?

What is the CPU architecture? Apktool requires aapt2 for recompiling which is included in apktool jar file only for some OS and architectures.
